# Maven Install Issues in command window

Tags: maven, command, cmd

I am trying to set up some Java code locally and need to do a the maven install first. In the directory with my pom.xml, I am trying to run the following:

```
mvn221 install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn221 eclipse:eclipse
```

When I run the first command, I get a `mvn221' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have the following defined in environment variables:

```
C:\Subversion>echo %M2%
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin

C:\Subversion>echo %M2_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-2.2.1
```

I also have this in my PATH variable `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation
\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin`.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears to me you were told to compile in this manner, by someone who has more than one version of Maven installed. Maven 2.2.1 would now be considered an old version of Maven.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
 mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

If you open the folder `explorer %M2%` you will see the batch file is named `mvn.bat` or just `mvn`. So, obviously, there is no `mvn221` that can be `recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Got it?

Comment: I tried this "C:\Subversion>mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true" and got this "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\" Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation". I don't have a jdk installed, only a jre. Can I point it to that?

Comment: you need to set `JAVA_HOME` in your system's `environment variables`. BTW, what do you see when you do this `%JAVA_HOME%` BTW, where is JDK installed? Is the path shown in error incorrect?

Comment: No, I don't have any JDK's currently installed. I have 2 JRE's installed (JRE 1.5.0_22 and JRE6). Does JAVA Home need to point to a JDK? The path above for java home is invalid as that directory does not exist. Would pointing JAVA HOME to a jre work or does it need to be a JRE?

Comment: You can't compile code with a JRE (Java Runtime Environment). You require a JDK (Java Development Kit).

Comment: as @MarkO'Connor correctly pointed, get a JDK installed (it's free).

Answer (score 1):

mvn221 is not the command. It is mvn. Do an mvn install